# What is the type of "abc" in C++?

Tags: c++

What is the type of "abc" in C++? Candidates could be `const char*` or `char*` .

Is there anything else one could think of?

Comment: It's actually `const char[4]`.

Comment: I came across a strange clang++ compiler behavior using c++11 std::regex_replace. The compiler wouldn't accept:

`std::string text = "Quick brown fox";`
`std::regex vowel_re("a|e|i|o|u");`
 
error --> `std::cout << '\n' << std::regex_replace(text, vowel_re, "[$&]") << '\n';`

works --> `std::cout << '\n' << std::regex_replace(text, vowel_re, std::string("[$&]")) << '\n';`

Comment: @tisch That's an *entirely* unrelated question (and I believe you have to pass in `std::string{"[$&]"}`)

Comment: @Barry the non-compiling line is from: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/regex_replace
That's why I was wondering.

Comment: @tisch: Then ask about that instead. Note that the code in the example works fine, at least with g++ (GCC) 4.9.2.

Comment: My bad, I didn't scroll down far enough for the `const CharT*` overload. Yeah, with the string literal the code works fine for me on every compiler. If that's the question you want to ask, you should ask it. Separately.

Answer (score 1):

On tutorialspoint I tried:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
   cout << typeid("abc").name() << endl; 
   cout << typeid ( const char * ).name() << endl;
   cout << typeid( char * ).name() << endl;
   cout << typeid( char[4]).name() << endl;
   cout << typeid( const char[4]).name() << endl;

   return 0;
}
```

Output is:

A4_c
PKc
Pc
A4_c
A4_c

seems char[4] or const char[4] but certainly not char* or const char*

Comment: It's `const char[4]`, as per C++11 §2.14.5 ¶8 (*Ordinary string literals and UTF-8 string literals are also referred to as narrow string literals. A narrow string literal has type “array of n `const char`”, where n is the size of the string as defined below, and has static storage duration (3.7).*)

Comment: Don't use `typeid` to tell the type. It's sometimes guaranteed by the standard to give you the wrong answer.

Comment: I would have guessed it would be const char[4] too. And I used typeid to illustrate. For a more pure answer you'd write overloads probably templated for the number in char[N] and see which one prints.

Comment: What's the differences between char[] and char[4] in C? does array type in C include length?